# Flutter Dev, did you know how to fix this icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When you use vscode and call **Icon(Icons."the icon")** to your code, the icon always showed up in the code line number section right (I don't about Android Studio). The scale icon that I called doesn't appear on the side, then when I hover my cursor, the scale image is broken. how do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

**This is the code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/constants/color_constant.dart';
import 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/user_page/collection/collection_page.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/user_page/home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/user_page/profile/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/pages/user_page/search/auction_page.dart';

class PageNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageNavBar> createState() => _PageNavBarState();
}

class _PageNavBarState extends State<PageNavBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  void changePage(int? index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('button pressed');
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 35,
        ),
        backgroundColor: kRedColor,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      body: <Widget>[
        HomePage(0),
        AuctionPage(1),
        CollectionPage(2),
        ProfilePage(3),
      ][currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BubbleBottomBar(
        hasNotch: true,
        fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end,
        opacity: 0.2,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: changePage,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(16),
        ),
        elevation: 8,
        tilesPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        items: const <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kDarkBlue,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.dashboard_outlined,
              color: kBlackColor,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.dashboard_rounded,
              color: kModerateCyan,
            ),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kDarkBlue,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.scale_outlined,
              color: kBlackColor,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.scale,
              color: kPowderBlue,
            ),
            title: Text('Logs'),
          ),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kDarkBlue,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.collections_outlined,
              color: kBlackColor,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.collections,
              color: kLightRedColor,
            ),
            title: Text('Logs'),
          ),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kDarkBlue,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person_outline,
              color: kBlackColor,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: kLightOrange,
            ),
            title: Text('Logs'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related to Flutter or Dart in any way - that's the IDE issue you are using (it seems that you are using Visual Studio Code).

In fact, this is a known issue that is mentioned in the Flutter context [here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3470#issuecomment-879004511) and globally [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119786).

Comment: that's kinda unfortunate, but thank you for answering my question