# Flutter - Some icons are not found

Tags: flutter, icons

I'm trying to use `Icon(Icons.factory)`  but it not displayed: in VSCode and even in my app.

Do you know why? (I saw I need to add `font_awesome_flutter` or `material_design_icons_flutter` but is it mandatory?)

I'm using `cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4` & `uses-material-design: true` in my **pubspec.yaml**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Dev, did you know how to fix this icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156425/flutter-dev-did-you-know-how-to-fix-this-icon)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any icon with name **factory** in the cupertino documentation but if you want to add any icon which is not yet present in your ide's options, simply visit flutters cupetino docs and click on the icon you want. For example the paperlane icon which is not yet available in the options

static const IconData paperplane = IconData(0xf733, fontFamily: iconFont, fontPackage: iconFontPackage);

change above code to

static const IconData paperplane = IconData(0xf733, fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.iconFont, fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage);

then you can use the font in your code as

Icon(paperplane)

Remember to update your cupertino package and import the file for some icons to work