# How to fix const Icon(Icons.person) Flutter error?

Tags: flutter

Hi I keep getting an error when trying to run main.dart due to the following error:

```
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: FormHelper.inputFieldWidget(
              context,
              const Icon(Icons.person), <---- This line over here 
              "Username",
              "Username",<---- This line over here
```

I have found this answer: [Flutter Dev, did you know how to fix this icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156425/flutter-dev-did-you-know-how-to-fix-this-icon)

but I tried it from VS code and android studio.

Error received:

```
error: The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [...] lib\screens\login_page.dart:115)
```

Question:

Why I am getting this error and how to avoid it?

Comment: what error you facing ?

Comment: @JohnJoe error: The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [...] lib\screens\login_page.dart:115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `prefixIcon` as one of the parameter, and add it after the two `String`.

```
 Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: FormHelper.inputFieldWidget(
              context,
              "Username",
              "Username",
              prefixIcon:Icon(Icons.person), <---- add prefixIcon here
```

Comment: Thank you this could you provide a little context for this error and for the answer just to understand